# Extracting FB post comments when the omniauth token expires

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, koala, omniauth-facebook

I have a Rails app which allows users to login via Facebook and do wall posts, I have a separate background process will run periodically to collect comments for those wall posts (via Facebook) and extract them and update in my local database.

I use `omniauth` and `'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'` for login/authentication and `"koala", "~> 1.10.0rc"` for facebook posts/comments extraction.

My problem is, the authentication token which I'm getting from `omniauth` is expiring after some time, but my background process needs a valid authentication token to extract the comments (because the background process can run at any time, not only when the user is logged in).

Can someone direct me to the correct path on how to do this kind of a implementation?